# Good ways to improve rep without asking and answering questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I am new to this account as I lost my login to both my old account and its email. I am trying to get back to the level I was before, and get back to my old privileges, but I need questions or to give answers, both of which are slow right now. Are there any ways I can get rep from doing things *other* than asking and answering questions?

Comment: SE can probably help you recover your original account,  [send them an email](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/contact). Out of curiosity what was your original account?

Comment: Oh wow, now that I think about it I don't remember the name exactly. It was Mr followed by summodd amount of underscores. I do remember my email, though!

Comment: @Robotnik Im pretty sure I couldn't ask questions any more cuz people didn't read one of mine through and I couldn't fix it anyway so... I guess this is good!

Comment: Related [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). Anyway, if your old account is on the question-ban and you created this new account to ask a question, then you're in danger of getting suspended for avoiding the ban though.

Comment: @antimo while that is a benefit to creating this account, it was not made to swerve the curve. I lost my login info and the email account for it was long gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [help page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) for this.

The literal answer to your question is suggested edits (which give +2 reputation if accepted).  But it may well be easier to ask questions.